# How to handle fixed and variable [assembly] items if both seem to be present mandatory inside one file?

Tags: c#, git, continuous-integration, assemblyinfo, gitversion

I'm setting up a Build Server, also known as a Continuous Integration Server, based on Jenkins, for building C# applications and DLLs.

I have an `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, which contains two kinds of information:

Fixed information, like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Application title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("MyCompany")]
...
```

... and variable information, like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("Sha.99560ad4873ab9e04bb8f262aafb5b3ee2fb6c1e")]
```

(This is generated by the command `dotnet-gitversion /updateassemblyinfo`)

The idea is that all those `[assembly]` entries come together in order to uniquely define every built binary (Application.exe, right-click and ask for "Details"), based on its commit hash.

As you can see, the first `[assembly]` entries are fixed, while the last one is variable.

So, I would like to have the first three ones in GIT, and the last one in `.GitIgnore` (or ignored by GIT in another way), but how to do that?

As far as I have understood

- the mentioned `[assembly]` like `[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Application title")]` must be put in `AssemblyInfo.cs` (is that true?), but also:
- the command `dotnet-gitversion /updateassemblyinfo` hardcodedly updates the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` (is that true?).

So, there are two possibilities:

- Either I only check in a part of `AssemblyInfo.cs` into GIT (is this even possible?)
- Either I find a way to put one of the `[assembly]` items in another file than `AssemblyInfo.cs` (is this even possible?)

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Git stores *commits*. The commits then store files, with each commit having a full snapshot of *every* file. When you pick a commit to extract, Git copies the files out of the commit. If you need to put together some fixed and some variable parts at this commit-extraction time, *you* must supply that part. A CI build system like Jenkins *should* provide tools to do this; Git generally *should not* (although there's a Git feature called "smudging" that you could theoretically abuse to do this if your build system is inadequate—but it is better to fix the build system instead).

Comment: Have you tried splitting the `[assembly]` attributes between several files? Like, create a `FixedAssemblyInfo.cs` and keep all fixed values there, and let that `otnet-gitversion /updateassemblyinfo` command update the normal `AssemblyInfo.cs` which will only have dynamic, generated data in it.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko: this is exactly my question: can I do that? Can I create a `FixedAssemblyInfo.cs` for the fixed, which goes into GIT, and a `AssemblyInfo.cs` for the variable ones, which does not go into GIT? Or do I need to create an `AssemblyInfo.cs` for the fixed, which goes into GIT, and a `VariableAssembly.cs` for the variable ones, who don't go into GIT? Or even something else? Can I expect any side-effects of putting `[assembly:...]` items in a file, whose name is different than `AssemblyInfo.cs`?

Comment: I can't think of any side effects of this, to be honest. The technique to have GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs for the solution is not new. The fastest way to find this out is to try. Take one of your projects and set it up like that, run your build and see the results - you'll know by the Details of the resulting DLL whether you get what you expect.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko: I don't have the opportunity to test your solution, but I believe it might work. Please write your solution as an answer, I'll accept it and reward you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the `[assembly]` attributes between several files:

- for example, keep all fixed values in `FixedAssemblyInfo.cs`, commit it
- let the `dotnet-gitversion /updateassemblyinfo` command update the normal `AssemblyInfo.cs` which will only contain dynamic values in this case. Don't commit this file

The main idea is that the same `[assembly]` attributes are not duplicated in both places.