# dotnet-gitversion "ShortSha" /updateassemblyinfo : Cannot find the .git directory

Tags: c#, .net, git, gitversion

As explained in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72227138), I would like to add the commit hash of my sources to my executable or DLL.

In order to do this, I would like to work with the following command:

```
dotnet-gitversion "ShortSha" /updateassemblyinfo
```

I have already created a `FixedAssemblyInfo.cs` in order to protect the rest of my `[assembly]` tags, but now when I try to run the mentioned command, I get the error message:

```
Cannot find the .git directory
```

I have launched the command in different ways:

- In the main directory of my Visual Studio solution, where the `.git` directory is present.
- In the subdirectory of my Visual Studio project, some subdirectory levels under the directory where the `.git` directory is present.
- Generally the `.git` directory is hidden. I have unchecked the `Hidden` checkbox in that directory's details, but no luck.
- I have launched `dotnet-gitversion` from a command prompt, a command prompt, run as administrator, and from the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017".

Now, you can guess, it's my idea to add the `dotnet-gitversion "ShortSha" /updateassemblyinfo` command as a pre-build event, but if I can't even run it as a simple command, how can I launch it as a pre-build event?

For your information, the full pre-build event looks as follows:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
dotnet-gitversion "ShortSha" /updateassemblyinfo
```

Does anybody have an idea?

O, before I forget: what I'm trying to achieve, is simply the creation of the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, containing (at least) the `"ShortSha"` of my source code. In top of this I would like to have it as a pre-build event, in order to have this information, every time I compile my project.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read [the doc](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/cli/arguments) correctly : `dotnet-gitversion` interprets its first argument as the path to the root of the project. `ShortSha` doesn't fit the bill.

You probably want to use the `/showvariable` option, which indicates to also set `/output json`.

Comment: Almost there: I've just launched `dotnet-gitversion . /showvariable "ShortSha" /updateassemblyinfo`, it gives the correct "ShortSha" indeed. Adding things like `/output file` or `/output json` also gives expected behaviour, but `dotnet-gitversion . /updateassemblyinfo /showvariable "ShortSha"` still does not work: `AssemblyInfo.cs` only gets updated when it already exists and it does not contain the `ShortSha` or the `Sha`, which is exactly I'm looking for in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Comment: This must be a joke: I've emptied my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file and I've ran `dotnet-gitversion . /updateassemblyinfo`. As a result, I see the entire JSON on my screen, my `AssemblyInfo.cs` gets updated ... but only with "AssemblyVersion", "AssemblyFileVersion" and "AssemblyInformationalVersion". Oh, I get it: I need to configure my `gitversion` in such a way that the "AssemblyInformationalVersion" "only" contains the information I want (like the `ShortSha`). Do you know how to do that configuration?

Comment: Almost there: I've just ran `dotnet-gitversion init` in my project directory (a subdirectory my GIT directory) and now I have a `GitVersion.yml` file, but I don't know how to configure them in order to get the "Informational" things right. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: F... it, this is not honest anymore: you have solved my problem (how to avoid that "cannot fine the .git directory" error message), I will now check how to configure `GitVersion.yml` in order to have a better `AssemblyInformationalVersion` entry in my assembly file.

Comment: In the meantime, I found a way to configure my `GitVersion.yml` file. As you have helped me a lot, I granted you the bounty. Unfortunately my problem still isn't completely finished, I'm now following this SuperUser question in order to get a complete understanding: https://superuser.com/questions/1724553/how-to-copy-in-clipboard-detailed-information-of-a-file